# create Form without using Gii

Tags: php, yii

i searched on  [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20make%20form%20in%20yii&oq=how%20to%20make%20form%20in%20yii&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.5631j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&q=how%20to%20make%20form%20without%20using%20gii%20in%20yii) but i didn't find my answer.

i have created one small webapp in yii. now i am making same app manually to explore more future of its(Yii).

i want to know that how to create **form,model & controller** without using Gii tools. i know this thing using Gii.

Please suggest me any docs or tutorials which explained step by step procedure.

i have refereed [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder#basic-concepts) but it's not clear.

Thank you again.

Comment: just write them by hand ... or ... generate them using gii :))

Comment: i am looking for some sample of code for start up...

Comment: Just generate form and tune to your need or take as example and create from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer [this forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/45890-ajax-validation-is-not-performed-for-second-model/page__p__216101#entry216101) to get start up for your code...

and then you can go through [this wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#defining-model-class) for more reference..

Hope it may help you...

Example form from docs:

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe=false;

    private $_identity;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('username, password', 'required'),
            array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
            array('password', 'authenticate'),
        );
    }

    public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: 
**For generating controller:**
generate MessageController.php 
**For generating views:**
first make directory 
mkdir /Webroot/demo/protected/views/message 
generate helloworld.php 
generate index.php